# How to ask for recommendation letter from someone already knew me?

Tags: recommendation-letter

due to covid, I think I will not be able to meet him in person. Writing him an email is the only option. In the email, should I introduce again to him who I am? He already knew and remembered my name.
Could you please tell me a format I could use?

Comment: What you do mean by format? If you are sure this guy knows who you are, you don't have to introduce yourself. But if your meeting is a long time ago, you maybe should, depending on your interactions.

Comment: So I should reintroduce who I am even if he already know my name? Is that common courtesy? The last time we exchanged email was 1.5 months ago, is that considered a long time in your opinion?

Comment: What exactly was your interaction? It will depend on this. If you worked closely together for a long time, probably noz.

Comment: @FARRAF 1.5 months is a *very short* time. I have had recommendation letters from people I have not seen in a year (of course, people who had had enough interaction with me to know what to write on the letter).

Comment: No I never worked with him. I just went to a lot of his classes, and I also took PhD class from him

Comment: Well, if you took a lot of his classes, you can probably say how much his personal skills are, if he cares for students, knows their name (which also depends on class size). Was there an exam? Oral? It is hard to comment on some guy I never met.

Comment: I will try to get rec from him. I mean it is not the best but there is nothing else I can do at least for this cycle. 
I am just asking about what to include in the email to ask for his recommendstion.

Comment: If he has good skills and interacted with you a lot in class, it would be strange to introduce yourself. But before you think a lot, just include this info.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, emails are a formal kind of communication, so it shouldn't hurt to compose and format formally.

Depending on how well you know each other, the "introduction" can be as long as an attached curriculum vitae or as short as a line of "I am Jon Doe".

If you've contacted that person in just a month and a half (which is quite short), you can go brief in this part and just say "I'm Jon Doe" and continue on describing your desires (tell them you want a reference letter). Try to correctly evaluate their familiarity with you - not every professor remembers their course students *that well*, in which case you may still want to include more details, up to a complete copy of your CV.

In addition, for these kinds of emails (requesting work or help from others), I prefer to err on the side of safety by *being professional*.

The last time I asked a professor for a recommendation letter around half a year ago, in a very similar situation to you. I attended courses from this professor and participated in contests and won good prizes (where all teammates were MSc students in his lab). I had not worked in research projects in his lab. I ended up writing my request email like this:

> Dear Prof. Jon Doe,
>
> I am iBug. I'm applying for a plumber at Super Mario Bro's Institution and I'm looking for a referral letter.
>
> I attended your courses [course A] and [course B] and received grades of A+ and A, respectively. I also took part in [example competition] in a team and won the 1st prize. My full CV is attached in this email, too.
>
> I'd be very glad if you can write a letter for me. I'm looking forward to hearing from you.
>
> Best wishes,
> iBug

Be sure to change specific wording / sentences according to your situations.